# Maven archetype + Velocity: how to show the date

Tags: maven-3, velocity, maven-archetype

I have a maven archetype project. When I use this archetype I want that some files report the actual date. I tried with $date but Velocity does not recognize it. I found something called DateTools but I don't know how can I use it. It's the first time I use Velocity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Maven Archetype plugin doesn't come bundled with Velocity Tools. I've added it by modifying the Maven Archetypes Plugin. Follow these steps, presuming you're using Maven 2.2.1:

```
svn co -q http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/archetype/tags/maven-archetype-2.2
cd maven-archetype-2.2
curl -k -O https://raw.github.com/gist/3404715/59c7fa1c20c60e2a165de4109c2acffb8026febd/velocity-tools.patch
patch -p0 -i velocity-tools.patch
mvn install
```

The modified Maven Archetype plugin will now be installed locally.

`$date` usage in your templates should now render, e.g.

```
The date is $date
```

...to:

```
The date is Aug 20, 2012 4:40:22 PM
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works like a charm. Will this patch be applied in a future release of maven-archetype-plugin?

Comment: Dunno, I just wrote it this morning :-) I think the focus could be on Maven 3.

Comment: Still working with maven-archetype-plugin 3.0.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

(Apologies for resurrecting an old question, but I have just worked through a way to achieve this without the need to pull and patch the plugin).

For anyone that wants to be able to reference date fields in their maven archetype templates, I was able to get it working with the following set of definitions at the top of my pom.xml template

```
#set( $str = "" )
#set( $dt = $str.getClass().forName("java.util.Date").newInstance() )
#set( $year = $dt.getYear() + 1900 )
```

If you already have object based variables available to your template at the point that you insert those lines, you can scratch the $str declaration and use one of your variables instead as it doesn't really matter where you get the reference to Class.forName() from.

NOTE: My attempts to get this working with Calendar.getInstance() were unsuccessful.

Comment: To not use deprecated APIs, this also works:

#set($year = $str.getClass().forName("java.time.Year").getMethod("now").invoke(null).toString())

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, with a formatter:

```
#set( $ldt = $package.getClass().forName("java.time.LocalDateTime").getMethod("now").invoke(null) )
#set( $dtf = $package.getClass().forName("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter").getMethod("ofPattern", $package.getClass()).invoke(null, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") )
#set( $date = $ldt.format($dtf) )
```

Comment: Kinda ironic that you use package. While it is a string and the package variable is always set, so that this is completely valid, the fact that you use getClass on a variable named package to then get a different class from a different package is kind of funny. This seems like the neatest solution if you don't want to rely on changing a default plugin (maven archetype)

Comment: You made me spot this useless .forName("java.lang.String"), thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I have some issues though when using this code. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44350467/2877358 Care to take a look what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to trim down the solution from @maaxiim to a single line:

```
#set( $year = $package.getClass().forName("java.util.Date").newInstance().getYear() + 1900 )
```

The $package variable will always be available from the maven archetype plugin.  The other builtins work as well, but most of them are quite long, and $artifactId.getClass() just looks... wrong.