# Setting dynamic velocity properties for archetype maven projects

Tags: java, maven, metadata, velocity, maven-archetype

I am creating an archetype and want to create a project wide available property containing things like the current date and an all lower case variant of the artifact id. I found [the following post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43867921/2877358), that shows how it normally should be possible.

I tried adding this to the archetype-metadata.xml like so:

```
    ...
    <requiredProperty key="artifactIdLower">
        <defaultValue>${artifactId.toLowerCase()}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="ldt">
        <defaultValue>${package.getClass().forName("java.time.LocalDateTime").getMethod("now").invoke(null)}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="dtf">
        <defaultValue>${package.getClass().forName("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter").getMethod("ofPattern", $package.getClass().forName("java.lang.String")).invoke(null, "dd MMM yyyy")}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="date">
        <defaultValue>${ldt.format($dtf)}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    ...
```

The property `artifactIdLower` works like a charm, but the `ldt`, `dtf` and `date` don't seem to work, giving the error:

```
Null reference [template 'dtf', line 1, column 1] : ${package.getClass().forName("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter").getMethod("ofPattern", $package.getClass().forName("java.lang.String")).invoke(null, "dd MMM yyyy")} cannot be resolved.
```

After that I tried to see where in the chain this null reference comes from. I was able to set `pkgClass` to `$package.getClass()` (or to `$package.Class`),

but after that I was unable to set `$strClass` to `$package.getClass().forName("java.lang.String")` or to `$pkgClass.forName("java.lang.String")` (funnily enough, both `pkgClass` and `strClass` should be a Class object).

This made me wonder if there is a restriction on using reflection inside the archetype-metadata.xml.

My question is: how can I set dynamically generated property values (like above) that can be used project wide?

I don't want to have to define these properties in every file that I create, because there might be more properties that I want to add later.

**Edit**:
I tried to instead create a `generalproperties.vm` file that contained the #set directives. This file would then be loaded by every file on the first line using #parse("generalproperties.vm"). While I did get the file to be parsed from within the pom.xml file, it didnt behave as I wanted.

The following input

```
test
$null
#set( $ldtClass = $package.getClass().forName("java.time.LocalDateTime") )
$ldtClass.Name
$ldtClass.getMethod("now")
#set( $ldtNowMethod = $ldtClass.getMethod("now") )
$ldtNowMethod.Name
#set( $clsLoader = $package.getClass().getClassLoader() )
$clsLoader
#set( $ldtClass2 = $clsLoader.loadClass("java.time.LocalDateTime") )
$ldtClass2.Name
$ldtClass2.getMethod("now")
#set( $ldtNowMethod2 = $ldtClass2.getMethod("now") )
$ldtNowMethod2.Name
#set( $ldt = $ldtNowMethod2.invoke($null) )
$ldt
#set( $dtf = $package.getClass().forName("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter").getMethod("ofPattern", $package.getClass().forName("java.lang.String")).invoke($null, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") )
$dtf
```

Generated the following output:

```
test
$null
java.time.LocalDateTime
$ldtClass.getMethod("now")
$ldtNowMethod.Name
$clsLoader
$ldtClass2.Name
$ldtClass2.getMethod("now")
$ldtNowMethod2.Name
$ldt
$dtf
```

The first 3 outputs are as expected, but after that I don't get the results I want. If someone is able to solve either of the above issues (with the metadata file or the generalproperties file), it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
...
<requiredProperty key="date">
    <defaultValue>${package.getClass().forName("java.time.LocalDateTime").getMethod("now").invoke(null).format($package.Class.forName("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter").getMethod("ofPattern", $package.Class).invoke(null, "dd MMM yyyy"))}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
...
```

Comment: I am still getting the following error: `INFO: Null reference [template 'date', line 1, column 1] : ${package.getClass().forName("java.time.LocalDateTime").getMethod("now").invoke(null).format($package.Class.forName("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter").getMethod("ofPattern", $package.Class).invoke(null, "dd MMM yyyy"))} cannot be resolved.` I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3 Ultimate edition

Comment: What's the version of your maven-archetype-plugin ? I use 3.0.1

Comment: I am also using that version. How do you create your archetype?

Comment: What do you mean? How do I generate a project? with archetype:generate.

Comment: What is your Maven version? Mine is 3.5.0

Comment: Ahh maybe that is the problem. I'm using 3.0.5, not 3.5.0

Comment: And maven 3.3.9 when creating the project in intellij

Comment: I now tried updating to 3.5.0. I used the project generation from inside IntelliJ (and made sure to select the correct mvn version), but still got the same error. After that I tried to run mvn archetype:generate from the command line, but the problem persisted. Here is a pastebin of the output: https://pastebin.com/cURQ3fWq

Comment: On your pastebin I see line 8: maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate, it works for me with maven-archetype-plugin v3.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't see that. I assumed that with my dependencies set and using the newest mvn, that the right version would be used. Am I right that I can use -Dversion?

Comment: You should use mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Is there a way to setup maven so that it uses 3.0.1 by default when using `archetype:generate`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it could help somebody what I noticed.

When I had something like:

```
<requiredProperty key="packageId"></requiredProperty>
<requiredProperty key="packageIdInPathFormat">
    <defaultValue>${package.getClass().getMethod("replace").invoke($packageId, ".", "/")}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

It was not evaluating expression in property `packageIdInPathFormat`.

But when I did something like:

```
<requiredProperty key="packageId"></requiredProperty>

<requiredProperty key="tempPackageId">
   <defaultValue>${packageId}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>

<requiredProperty key="packageIdInPathFormat">
   <defaultValue>${tempPackageId.replace(".", "/")}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Expression was evaluated.

Comment: It looks like properties are evaluated in some alphabetic order...

Answer (score 0):

The only restriction I could think of is if you are using the `SecureUberspector` instead of the standard Uberspector in your Velocity configuration properties. But you wouldn't be able to get the `java.time.LocalDateTime` class, so it's not the case, unless maybe if you are using an old Velocity version. With Velocity 1.7 I am able to get a reference to the `now()` method and to call it.

Also, are you sure that the direct Java version is working properly? For instance, I read in the `Class.getClassLoader()` javadoc that "some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader."

Comment: I am using the latest version of maven archetype which uses velocity 1.7 I think. The weird thing is the inconsistency between the archetype-metadata file and the parsed file. The parsed file is unable to get the method `now` where the metadata file cannot even reach the class by using `forName`. Any thought on that?